# when l submirt it send to email with pdf file and add that pdf file link to google sheet column AC

Tags: google-apps-script

```js
const newStaffDataSendToMailwithPdf = (data) => {
  try {

      const sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Quote'); // Check if the sheet name is correct
      if (staus !== 'Request Quote') {
        const leavePdf = generatePDF(sheet); // Make sure you have the generatePDF function defined
      var message = {
        to:  '',
         subject: "GJENGE MAKERS LTD",
         body: `Hello everyone`,
         name: `Quotation`,
        attachments: [{ fileName: name + job, content: leavePdf.getBytes(), mimeType: 'application/pdf' }]
      };
      MailApp.sendEmail(message);

      return "Email sent successfully";
    }
```

when l submit it send to email with pdf file so what I want is to add that pdf link to google sheet column AC so mean that each transaction or each submit have pdf link in google sheet column AC